# Legendary engrams, are they biased towards the character class I'm decoding it on?

Tags: destiny

When I decode a legendary engram, and it produces a legendary item, sometimes it's for a different class.

Is this truly random, so that my warlock has just as large chance of getting a legendary as the two other classes, or will the legendary most of the time be for my class?

Comment: It's got to be weighted towards your own class as I've only extremely rarely gotten stuff for other classes. Since I have no actual proof though, leaving this as a comment.

Comment: I expect so too, just hoping someone had a definitive answer.

Comment: Its pretty much completely random, I have gotten a full suit of purple Titan armor from engrams now, I play as hunter. I have not gotten one piece of Hunter armor that is purple from an engram, I have bought all my pieces.

Comment: How to win friends and influence people Cryptarch style.

Answer (score 1):

They are not biased towards your current character, legendary and exotic armour engram rewards are based on RNG (Random Number Generation) and so are completely random. For example the exotic engrams that Xur sells from time to time can give you an item that could be for any of the 3 classes.

See this image for an example of a legendary engram, saying it could be for (Random Class):
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/vbw8GIeOx3A/maxresdefault.jpg

However if you get an item for a different class, it's not the end of the world. When you decide to start a second character, or 'alt', you'll have nice equipment waiting for them! Either that, or you can just dismantle for some ascendant materials.

Answer (score -1):

Its random but most of the time its for your class. I dont have exact numbers, but in my case it is like 1 out of 10 or something like that.